# Running .exe files on linux servers

Tags: node.js, heroku, exe

so I have deployed my node.js application on heroku but my application uses the help of .exe files to run which were generated on windows. Since heroku runs on a Linux server I am unable to run my executables on the deployed application, but it does run locally. I tried to use wine to run the executables, using the wine build pack but it didn't help as it returned an enoent error.
It would return with an error message of `spawn sync path/to/executable ENOENT`

I also tried deploying using a docker file but the wine docker file doesn't seem to generate https://hub.docker.com/r/suchja/wine

Is there any workaround for this problem? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Just put your code onto your heroku server and run there `node app.js`. No need to bundle your app. Why do your create a exe when you want to run the app on a linux server?!

Comment: @Marc His node js app which he runs through `node ...` relies on windows executable files.
@Kunza get your docker image running locally, then try to deploy it on Heroku. Share the error messages you see in your docker container when it doesn't run on Heroku.

Comment: @tin nguyen I'm actually struggling with creating the dockerfiles. I followed the tutorial given hub.docker.com/r/suchja/wine here but this didn't give me the output that they talk about  if i try making a docker image independently The console seems to run but I don't see any output. There seems to be a docker image generated when I print the list of images on my local computer but when I run this particular image I don't get any response